# How to get element whicih satisfy condition considering two lists (Python / Pandas) without for loop

Tags: python, pandas, list, vectorization

I have two list like below :

```
A = [50,100,140]
B = [10,30,40,90,95,125]
```

I want to get element from list A, considering a condition related with list B.

1. I want to consider only the values limited element of A -30 :
   For example, for 50 of list A, I want to take only 30 and 40 from list B.
2. If there are no element from list B, with limit A+30 => We can select 50 for new list.

From that, I want to get new list like [50,140] because for 100 of list A, we see there is 125 < 100+30 .

Maybe we can use two for loop like

```
for ele in A :
   for ele2 in B :
```

But actually, I don't want to use it because my actual data is much bigger.

Is there anyway to do it without for loop? like `np.where` or `np.select` or `groupby` of Pandas?

Comment: Please provide some sample code as well as expected output

Comment: Uoops it's 140. Edited

Comment: In your example, what happens to 30 and 40 that you took from B list?